# Team burnup report

Tags: rally

What tools are available in Rally to generate a team burnup report? My research has made me aware of burnups based on iteration, release, and user story, but I'm looking to create a burnup report that encompasses all top-level user stories that a given team is working on without limiting the time of the report to a given release or iteration.

Is there a way to do this with the Rally SDK or some such?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you download the Rally plug-in for Excel.

[Rally/Excel install/user guide](http://help.rallydev.com/rally-add-excel-installation-user-guide)

This tool allows you to pull pretty much anything from Rally.

As to your specific question though a Burnup Chart is by definition and iterative report...basically they say between time A and Z this is how much we are planning on getting accomplished and here is where we currently are in our progress to that goal.  Without a defined time frame the report doesn't really tell you anything.  Its tough to define scope without it...

Can you be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish/demonstrate?

Comment: Frankly, I was tasked with finding the solution to this on behalf of someone else, and it has been so long that I've forgotten the details of this project. Sorry.

Anyway, my org is split between Linux and Windows, so an Excel dependency is non-ideal.